# Android ListView OnItemClick problem

Tags: android

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) { 
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HaberGoster.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, position);

    }
```

this is my code for starting a new activity while a tag is clicked on listview. The problem is when i click to a tag i want to get the postion at HaberGoster.class

what should i do to get postion of listview at other class

Comment: You want the x,y coordinates of where the ListView got clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "send" the position to the other class by putting it into the intent.

```
intent.putExtra("position", position);
```

And then read it in the second class:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int position = extras.getInt("position");
```